# mixing two lists same length python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to mix every element of two lists with eachother, they have the same length:

```
list1 = [(m0, m0+b), (m1, m1+b), (m2, m2+b),...]
list2 = [(n0, n0+b), (n1, n1+b), (n2, n2+b),...]
```

to create a list like this:

```
new_list = [((m0, m0+b), (n0, n0+b)), ((m0, m0+b), (n1, n1+b)), ((m0, m0+b), (n2, n2+b)),..., ((m1, m1+b), (n0, n0+b)), ((m1, m1+b), (n1, n1+b)), ((m1, m1+b), (n2, n2+b)), ..., ((m2, m2+b), (n0, n0+b)), ((m2, m2+b), (n1, n1+b)), ((m2, m2+b), (n2, n2+b)), ...]
```

Update:

Solution

```
from itertools import product

    list(product(list1, list2))
    [((m0, m0+b), (n0, n0+b)),
     ((m0, m0+b), (n1, n1+b)),
     ((m0, m0+b), (n2, n2+b)),
     ((m1, m1+b), (n0, n0+b)),
     ((m1, m1+b), (n1, n1+b)),
     ((m1, m1+b), (n2, n2+b)),
     ((m2, m2+b), (n0, n0+b)),
     ((m2, m2+b), (n1, n1+b)),
     ((m2, m2+b), (n2, n2+b))]
```

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
from itertools import product
list(product(list1, list2))
[((m0, m0+b), (n0, n0+b)),
 ((m0, m0+b), (n1, n1+b)),
 ((m0, m0+b), (n2, n2+b)),
 ((m1, m1+b), (n0, n0+b)),
 ((m1, m1+b), (n1, n1+b)),
 ((m1, m1+b), (n2, n2+b)),
 ((m2, m2+b), (n0, n0+b)),
 ((m2, m2+b), (n1, n1+b)),
 ((m2, m2+b), (n2, n2+b))]
```

Comment: output not exactly what Im willing to get :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a comprehension with `zip` and `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain

m = [ ... ]
n = [ ... ]
b = ...

new_list = list(chain(*(((m1, m2+b), (n1, n2+b)) for (m1, m2), (n1, n2) in zip(m, n))))
```

Comment: b is a float with a constant length so (_m, _m+b) does not work in this case 

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple